# Best practices for cooking steaks such as rib-eye at home

Tags: grilling, steak, pan, seasoning

I am looking for a best practices advise on cooking steaks such as rib-eye or club steaks at home so they come out similar to those at steakhouses.

Oven or Pan? How about the seasoning and cooking times?

Comment: I am answering as if this a question on best methods for cooking these cuts; if you are after specific recipes, that is off topic.  You can google countless recipes for these steaks on the internet.  I especially recommend reading the articles from Kenji Lopez Alt at the Serious Eats in his Food Lab column.

Comment: That other question, despite its high voting, is very poor.  It doesn't specify what kind of steak which is very key.  The only thing concretely specified is that outcome of medium-well, which is specifically not a good doneness for this type of steak.  I would suggest not closing this one as a duplicate.

Comment: Closing as duplicate will just put a message that the answer can be found over there... which it is, in all of the highly-upvoted answers...

Answer (score 0):

These cuts are both tender, and low in connective tissue.

They respond best to high-heat methods that cook them rapidly, to create flavor on the outside through browning, while leaving the inside less cooked, perhaps no more than medium rare to medium.

Some of the best methods for achieving this are:

- Pan frying or griddling
- Cooking over an open flame, as in a barbecue
- Using a sufficiently strong broiler or salamander

Some people are partial to using sous-vide methods, to get the core of the steak cooked ideally to the desired level and then finishing with one of these other methods (or even a blow torch) to create the browning and crustiness on the outside.

These cuts do not respond well to being cooked well done, or any of the low and slow methods like braising or barbecuing which are implicitly well done, as they don't have sufficient fat and connective tissue to melt and break down into gelatin to restore tenderness.  They will become tough and rubbery in such applications.

Comment: Thanks, great response. I would only ask about the type of pan recommended for these steaks.

Comment: All steaks benefit from a pan that retains heat well, and can sear them ideally.  Cast iron is a good choice, if well seasoned.  A good multiple layer stainless steel pan with an aluminum core is also a good choice.